# How? Follow path and change camera's track to from one object to another

Tags: animation, constraints

I have an empty parenting a camera and the empty is following a bezier curve thru a constraint.  I have the camera 'Track'ed to' a moon, but as the Empty/camera travels along the bezier curve I want to switch 'track to' from the moon to the earth at some definable point.  How can I do this?  Also the Empty/Camera contines to run beyond the end of the bezier curve.  How do I get the Empty/Camera to stop at a definable point and just focus on the earth

[image]

Comment: The focus bit is a separate question and should be edited out. Secondly, you can animate the influence of two Track To constraints to cross fade as necessary. Will this do what you need?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to animate the influence.  I can see how influence affects the camera but when I add keyframes for Location,Rotation,Scale, they do not know or respect the influence.  I've read up in the manual but how this works is not clear.  I have two track to constraints for my camera

Comment: No not animate location rotation and scale while influence is on, animate the influence. As in, right click the 0 to 1 value bar that says “influence“, and then click “add key frame”

Comment: Crikey - almost there.  I did not know / missed the add key frame right click on influence slider.  I want the camera pointed to moon (1) earth(0) and then rapidly turn to focus on the earth(1) moon(0) - but I can't quite get there.  As an animation the camera wants to animate around, I want a hard pivot.  Thx in advance TheLabCat

Comment: Hmm… Wait a minute! You don’t have to turn the first constraint off, because the second constraint will override it. Just skip the animation of the first constraint and see if that helps.

Comment: So when I add the first keyframe with camera pointing at moon(1) and about 50 frames in I add a keyframe with the camera pointing at the earth(1) the camera follows the curve and the second constraint slides smoothly from 0 to 1 taking the camera focus off of the moon as it slides the influence from 0 to 1.  I want the animation to hard switch from the moon to the earth, not slide into it and taking the camera off the moon - that slide causes the camera to point into space when I want it on the moon for it's trip around the moon.

Comment: Then just put the key frames right next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

As TheLabCat wrotes you can just add a second track to constraint to the earth.

Then you can animate the "influence" values of both constraints as you need it. 0 means no influence 1 means "full" influence.
So you should animate the value for your moon constraint from 1 to 0 and at the same time the value from the earth constraint from 0 to 1.

For the animation, use the object constraint "follow path", choose your path and insert keyframes in offset for value 0 and -100.

video tutorial here: https://youtu.be/qFv25Up6LzE

[image]

you can cross fade an animation in VSE.

Open VSE. Insert both movie strips or images sequences. Move them in that way that they do overlap. Select both. Then Shift-A -> Transition -> Cross. By moving the strips you can lengthen/shorten the crossfade-effect.

video tutorial for cross-fading: https://youtu.be/KgiXJvW5tvk

Comment: I need just a little more guidance - I added the 2nd Object Constraint on the camera and I can see how influence changes the camera but I don't know how to animate the influence for a cross fade.

Comment: you can cross fade this in VSE, i just made a tutorial about it. I will put the link in here. But honestly...these are now 3 questions in one post. Normally you should have only one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is 2 years old but I'll throw an answer in just in case anyone comes cross it.

When you fade from 1 *Track To* to another you need them to both share the same frame where one has an influence of 1 and the other has an influence of 0. Move along the time line a few frames and then change the influence of the first to 0 and the second to 1. If you press the record button above the timeline before setting the influence, it will automatically add a keyframe for each of the times you changed the influence setting.

This will create a pan to movement across those frames. If you want the camera to immediately snap straight from object to another object with the *Track To* just make sure the influence change from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 happens in the space of just two frames.